# Kendo Scheduler EditorTemplate - set recurrence date to selected date

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm working on a Kendo Scheduler, which has a custom EditorTemplate for adding a new task. And now, if I want to make a task that has to be recursive (that is, it is should be repeated daily, weekly, etc.), it does not, as standard, set it's recursive date to the selected date, but the actual date of the week.

I have tried to comment the EditorTemplate out, and I can see that it then sets the recursive date to the selected date - so as a standard it works as it should.

I have also tried to add some JavaScript to check the correct checkbox, but I could not get that to work as well

The recursive part of the template looks like:

```
<div data-container-for="recurrenceRule" class="k-edit-field">
  @(Html.Kendo().RecurrenceEditorFor(model => model.RecurrenceRule).Messages(m => 
        SchedulerHelper.MessageLocaliztion(this, m))
       .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:recurrenceRule" }))
</div>
```

Any idea how to make it work as it does as  standard ? Or make a EditorTemplate where you exclude the recursiveness, and it takes the standard ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of the **[SchedularEvent Framework](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/schedulerevent)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is the answer to your question, but we needed to set the change event in the kendoRecurrenceEditor (or kendoMobileRecurrenceEditor) so that when the user makes a change, it comes back into the parent event properly.  This was the direction from Kendo Support.

```
        recurrenceEditor.kendoRecurrenceEditor({
            start: new Date(event.start),
            value: event.recurrenceRule,
            timezone: self.scheduleConfig.timezone,
            messages: self.scheduleConfig.messages.recurrenceEditor,
            change: function () {
                event.set("recurrenceRule", this.value());
            }
        });
```